# Referencing a ts property in css file

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

In my typescript file, I have an object I am getting from an API that has an url property, for example:
`this.contentInfo.contentDetail.columnContent[0].image.path` 
gives me the url I will need to use to set the background image.

But we are using CSS to set the background image because depending on the width of the screen the image will change to a smaller version using a different path for example

`this.contentInfo.components[7].contentDetail.columnContent[1].image.path`
this would give me the smaller image path.

In our css we just have something like this

````
background-image: url("/stgw/digital/referrals/assets/Referred_M.png");```
````

I basically want to reference my object in the CSS like you can do in html

```
background-image: 
     url({{this.contentInfo.contentDetail.columnContent[0].image.path 
     }})
```

Is this possible?? If not how would anyone go about setting the background image in url with this being the css I will need to manipulate

```
#welcome-block {
     background-image: url("/stgw/digital/Referred_S.png");
     background-size: 100%;
     }
   @media (min-width: 960px) {
   #welcome-block {
      background-image: url("/stgw/digital/Referred_M.png");
      background-size: 100%;
    }
   }
   @media (min-width: 1280px) {
   #welcome-block {
     background-image: url("/stgw/digital/Referred_L.png");
     background-size: 100%;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

The supported alternative goes the other way (ts -> css), as you can bind to any property you can do something like this:

```
<div [ngStyle]="{ 'background-image': 'url(' + image + ')'}">
```

Comment: Yes I know you can set the css with ngstyle but how would I utilize that when looking at the @media min width

Comment: you set the class in the component according to the property you want,  and the @media  query modifies the class according to viewport.